# Fetch hidden product_id from database to jquery autocomplete plugin list

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using jquery autocomplete plugin for selecting data from database using PHP, MySql and Ajax.
The plugin operates good except fetching the product_id. When the plugin fetches the autocomplete list I want also to attach a hidden product_id to the products to differentiate the products for example in case of multiple products with the same product_name.

Below is the code that functions only with product_name.

```
    function select_name(){

     $("[id^='product_name']").focus(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      id = id.replace("product_name",'');
      $("[id^='product_name']").autocomplete({
          
          source: 'store_supply/fetch_autocomplete_name.php',
          select: function (event, ui) {
              var pro_nm = ui.item.value; 
              $.ajax({
                      url:"store_supply_manage/fetch_product_code.php",
                      method:"POST",
                      data:{pro_nm:pro_nm}, 
     //here I want to post a product_id when selecting the     product_name
                      dataType:"json",
                      success:function(data){

                          $('#mu_emri_'+id).val(data.mu_name);
                          $('#product_code_'+id).val(data.barCode);
                          $('#vat_vlera_'+id).val(data.vat_value_4);
                          $('#product_id'+id).val(data.product_id);

                          calculateTotal();
                      }
              });
          }  
          
       });
     });
    }

        //fetch_autocomplete.php

    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {

      $term = $_GET['term'];

      $query = $db->prepare("SELECT product_name FROM products 
                             WHERE product_name LIKE '%$term%'   LIMIT 10");
      $query->execute();

       $nr = $query->rowCount();

      if ($nr > 0) {
        while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
        $result[] = $row['product_name'];
        }
       }
      else {
        $result = array();
      }
      //return json result
       echo json_encode($result);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are preparing your SQL statement but interpolating the $term variable instead of parameterizing your query. In the example below I have parameterized your query.

---

As shown in the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), the data can be either:

> - An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> - An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

So you can just change your fetch_autocomplete.php to something like:

```php
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {

    $term = '%' . $_GET['term'] . '%';

    // parameterized query in nowdoc*
    $sql = <<<'SQL'
        SELECT id AS `value`, product_name AS `label`
        FROM products
        WHERE product_name LIKE :term
        LIMIT 10
        SQL;

    // prepare the query
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);

    // bind variables and execute
    $query->execute(['term'] => $term);

    // As fetchAll() returns an empty array if there are no matching
    // rows we do not need to check rows returned
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    
    // return json result
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

[* nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

Change `id` to whatever the name of your product id column is. Now, inside your `select` handler, `ui.item.value` will be the product id instead of its name.